# How to change the type of RDD element from list to Int?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Currently, my RDD looks like `[[2475], [1900], [2300]]`
I want my RDD to be like this `[2475, 1900, 2300]`

[image: Please Check the image]

Comment: can you post the code and outputs as formatted text instead of an image? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). also the code you've shared in the screenshot is missing some background info. it would be helpful to know what the `extractData` function does, and if the argument `countryCode` is supposed to be used in the `filterElevation` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` and extract the value from the inner lists.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[2475], [1900], [2300]]). \
    map(lambda r: r[0]). \
    collect()

# [2475, 1900, 2300]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `map()` transformation in your code for an array, then it will wrap the data inside an extra bracket. Instead use `flatMap()` transformation.